# How can I insert the original matched pattern (OLD STRING) into the result (NEW STRING) Using Microsoft Word's Find/Replace Feature?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, sed, microsoft-word-2016, string-manipulation

The find/replace feature in Microsoft Word usually has the same resulting output string no matter what input string matches the search pattern.

| INPUT | OUTPUT |
| --- | --- |
| `(1)` | `1.` |
| `(2)` | `1.` |
| `(3)` | `1.` |
| `(4)` | `1.` |
| `(5)` | `1.` |
| `(6)` | `1.` |
| `(7)` | `1.` |

For any search pattern ***p***, there exists a string ***out1*** such that for any string **in1**, if **in1** matches pattern ***p***, then **in1** gets replaced with **out1**.

That description is a little bit strange, so I will add something clearer:

In an example, suppose that the old version of the document contains numbers surrounded by parentheses, such as `(6)`.

Is there some way to capture the matched text and insert the matched text in the output?

The desired behavior, and our goal, is to remove the parentheses and place a dot at the end.

| INPUT | OUTPUT |
| --- | --- |
| `(1)` | `1.` |
| `(2)` | `2.` |
| `(3)` | `3.` |
| `(4)` | `4.` |
| `(5)` | `5.` |
| `(6)` | `6.` |
| `(7)` | `7.` |

Suppose we open up <kbd>Find</kbd> <kbd>Replace</kbd>...

... we then enter in the following information:

```
FIND WHAT:     (^#)
REPLACE WITH:  1.
```

[image: a screen capture of the find text and replace text dialog in Microsoft Word]

The above will have the following, undesirable, effect:

```
.--------.-------.
| BEFORE | AFTER |
.--------.-------.
| (1)    | 1.    |
.--------.-------.
| (2)    | 1.    |
.--------.-------.
| (3)    | 1.    |
.--------.-------.
| (4)    | 1.    |
.--------.-------.
```

How can we insert the matched pattern into the resulting output text?

I want to do something like this:

```None
    .--------.-------.
    | BEFORE | AFTER |
    .--------.-------.
    | (1)    | 1.    |
    .--------.-------.
    | (2)    | 2.    |
    .--------.-------.
    | (3)    | 3.    |
    .--------.-------.
    | (4)    | 4.    |
    .--------.-------.
```

Comment: It sounds like you're asking for ``^&``, but I don't understand your examples.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your examples, so I'm not sure if this is what you're asking, but if you want to make it 5. you would do find (5) replace with 5.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than separate find and replaces as shown in your example above to delete the brackets, you can instead do a wildcard find and replace. The trick is to separate out the parts - for the find, the first part is the opening round bracket, the second part is any digit(s), and the third part is the closing round bracket. Then in your replace, you just keep the second part and add the full stop.

A part in the find is enclosed in round brackets.

For the "range" of characters to search for, enclose them in the square brackets.

The / is to "escape" the special character so you can search for the opening and closing round brackets.

So the find is: ([/(])([0-9]@)([/)])
And the replace is:  \2.

Remember to select the option for Use wildcards.

This will find (5) or (11) for example, and replace with 5. and 11. respectively.